# page-specific bullets in openoffice impress

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-impress

I need to switch the bullets in an openoffice impress slideshow. In one page I need the "normal" round ball, in another I need a check sign, in another I need the x sign.

What I do is select the list in which I want to make the change and then do a

Format -> Style & Formatting -> RightClick on Outline -> Modify

and I select what I want in the bullet tab.

The problem is that the change is applied to the whole presentation, which is very weird since I'm **not** doing this change in "Slide Master" but just on the slide I want. I RTFM'ed, Googled, etc, but with no luck.

How can I select different bullets for different lists?

In case this matter, I'm in Ubuntu 10.04, and OpenOffice is 3.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do this is

Format -> Bullet and Numbering

This way is applied only to the current slide.